# Set Java language level in IntelliJ for OSX

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

Have a Java project, which is setup to build a .jar file. 
Java 1.7 is installed, and have set the project to Language Level 6.
However, it keeps compiling the jar files (via the artifact builder) to Java 1.7, so I get the following error when trying to run on a Java 1.6 JVM:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mycompany/myproject/MyClass : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

- Under  `File` -> `Other Settings` -> `Default Settigns...` -> `Compiler`, I've set "Project bytecode version" to 1.6,
- Also tried setting "Additional command line parameters" to `-target 1.6` and `-source 1.6`
- Have also added this line to `~/.bash_profile` (so that `java -version` returns `1.6.0_65`) and restarting IntelliJ:

  export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v '1.6*'`

But IntelliJ still keeps building the jar to Java 7, and it fails to run on JVM 1.6.  What might I try next?

[What is Project Language level in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714584/what-is-project-language-level-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Does your project maybe include some external libraries that are compiled for Java 7?

Comment: Awesome thought.  Hadn't thought to check the other libraries. But somehow in checking your hypothesis the issue resolved itself silently!  Mystery.  thanks!

Comment: File | Other Settings | Default Settings... change the settings for new projects created in IntelliJ IDEA, not for the project you currently have open. To change the settings for the current project, go to IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Compiler.

Comment: @yole, that's actually the answer. Trying repeatedly had found two routes to what seemed like the same thing.  Mystery solved.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the "Project bytecode version" setting under IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Compiler and not under File | Other Settings | Default Settings | Compiler.