# Java add text to a specific line in a file

Tags: java, file

I would like to know if it's possible to add a line in a File with Java.

For example myFile :

```
1: line 1
2: line 2
3: line 3
4: line 4
```

I would like to add a line fox example in the third line so it would look like this

```
1: line 1
2: line 2
3: new line
4: line 3
5: line 4
```

I found out how to add text in an empty file or at the end of the file but i don't know how to do it in the middle of the text without erasing the line.

Is the another way than to cut the first file in 2 parts and then create a file add the first part the new line then the second part because that feels a bit extreme ?

Thank you

Comment: You may use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289965/inserting-text-into-an-existing-file-via-java

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Java 7+ you can use the `Files` and `Path` class as following:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
lines.add(position, extraLine);
Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

To give an example:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\foo\\Downloads\\test.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

int position = lines.size() / 2;
String extraLine = "This is an extraline";  

lines.add(position, extraLine);
Files.write(path, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: Hello I tried to use this but I get an IDE error "usage of api which is not available at the configured language level". Apparently Path & Files are documented as 1.6+ but I'm using Java version 1.7 so it should work wright ? I don't really get it

Comment: Please check the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714584/what-is-project-language-level-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Even with that I keep seeing an error in my IDE but the code run so I will just ignore it thanks a lot !

Comment: Welcome :) I am not running InteliJ (running Eclipse myself), but i guess it is related to your IDE.

Comment: How can I extend this so I can add a line BEFORE a line with a certain string, e.g., add `new line` before that line that has `line 4` in it?

Answer (score 1):

You may read your file into an `ArrayList`, you can add elements in any position and manipulate all elements and its data, then you can write it again into file.

PD: you can not add a line directly to the file, you just can read and write/append data to it, you must manipulte de data in memory and then write it again.

let me know if this is useful for you