# How to specify where to save string in file

Tags: file, groovy

How to save string to file to specify place ? I use `path << 'string'` to save, but it give it on end of file. In destination to xml(`path`) file have `</databaseChangeLog>`. I want to save to file before that word occurs.

There is java solution [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276996/java-add-text-to-a-specific-line-in-a-file), but it is static line. My file will be dynamic, I don't know with line it will be.

```
def add_to_version() {
   def path = new File('C:/groovy/version-1.xml')       
   def branchId = "Promt"
   def lineCount = 0

  def count = path.eachLine { line ->        
    if(line.contains('<include file="' + branchId + '/' + branchId + '.xml" ')){
        wordCount++             
    }else if(lineCount == 1 ){
        println "package is there"
    }
 }
  if(lineCount == 0){
    path << '<include file="' + branchId + '/' + branchId + '.xml" ' + 'relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>'    
  }
}
```

code above do that :
[image: xml1]
     and I want to get xml like that :
[image]

Comment: please modify your question and provide an example content of your file and what should be in it after modification. in general: you have to read full file in memory, change loaded data, and write it back to file. in groovy you can use xmlparser (or xmlslurper) to read and manipulate xml.

Comment: I add my xml file and what i want :) Looking in xmlparser...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use xml parser like this:

```
def add_to_version(String branchId) {
   def path = new File('C:/groovy/version-1.xml')       
   def xml = new XmlParser().parse(path)
   xml.appendNode("include", [
      file:"${branchId}/${branchId}.xml",
      relativeToChangelogFile:"true"
   ])
   groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml, path.newOutputStream())
}
```

this variant will not keep the xml formatting and comments

however xml will be valid